# The sign of the regression coefficient and the correlation coefficient

Tags: regression, correlation

Why can't the regression coefficient and the correlation coefficient have different sign?

Answer (score 6):

I assume you are referring to regression with only 1 explanatory/independent/right-hand-side/$x$-variable. If there are multiple explanatory variables the statement is incorrect.

In Bivariate regression the regression coefficient ($b$) is:

$b = \rho \frac{sd(y)}{sd(x)}$

$\rho$ is the correlation coefficient, and $sd(x)$ and $sd(y)$ are the standard deviations of $x$ and $y$ respectively. Since standard deviations can only be positive the fraction can only be positive and the only thing determining the sign of $b$ is the sign of $\rho$.